# How to iterate multi_index

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, multi-index

here is my multi_index code:

```
struct tag_type {};
typedef boost::multi_index_container<ObjectStorage,
            bmi::indexed_by<
                // Type
                bmi::ordered_non_unique<
                    bmi::tag<tag_type>,
                    bmi::const_mem_fun<ObjectStorage, std::string, &ObjectStorage::getType>
                >
            >
        > ObjectWrapperSet;
```

Now I want to iterate through result of `find`.

```
ObjectWrapperSet::index<tag_type>::type &mObjectsByTypeViewer = 
    mObjectsSet.get<tag_type>()

 typedef ObjectWrapperSet::index<tag_type>::type::const_iterator ByTypeIt;
 ByTypeIt it = mObjectsByTypeViewer.find("Some type");
```

But how to get another/end iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
ByTypeIt end = mObjectsByTypeViewer.end();
```

Comment: But I need end iterator for search (find call), not for all `mObjectsByTypeViewer`. It will be the end for all objects in container, right?

Comment: Oh, if you mean you want to iterate over all the values having a certain key, then you should use `lower_bound()` instead of `find()`, and `upper_bound()` instead of `end()`.  Or you can call `equal_range()` to get the two bounds in a single call.  It works the same as the usual STL: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/equal_range.html